# Django ModelFormSet not submitting correctly

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am having trouble submitting a `modelformset` in my view. For some reason, the formset is not meeting is_valid criteria, whatever I set the actual data to.

Here is the relevant part of the view:

```
def admin_tools(request):
    ElectionFormSet = modelformset_factory(Election, exclude=('Complete',), formset=BaseElectionFormSet, extra=0)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        if 'edit_elections' in request.POST:
            election_formset = ElectionFormSet(request.POST)
            # print(formset)
            if election_formset.is_valid():
                election_formset.save()
                messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Election settings saved')
                return redirect(reverse('elections:home'))
            else:
                messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Problem')
                return redirect(reverse('elections:home'))

    else:
        election_formset = ElectionFormSet()

    return render(request, 'admin/admin_tools.html',{
        'formset': election_formset,
    })
```

Every time I submit the formset I get the problem message indicating the formset is not valid and I don't know why.

Here is form tag in the template:

```
<form method="post" action="">

    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class='card'>
            <div class='card-body w-75 mx-auto'>

                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-6 text-center'>

                        <p>Name<br>{{form.Name}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-6 text-center'>
                        <p>Videos<br>{{form.FlipGrid}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-12 text-center'>
                        <p>Description<br>{{form.Description}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-6 text-center'>
                        <p>Allow registration: {{form.CandidateReg}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-6 text-center'>
                        <p>Allow voting: {{form.VotingOpen}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div><p>{{form.id}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <div class='text-center'>
        <br><button type="submit" class='btn btn-outline-dark' name='edit_elections'>Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I'm not sure what the error would be here. My thought is that maybe each form should be submitted individually and not as a whole formset? I'm also not sure my csrf token is in the right place.

How do I get my formset to submit correctly?

Comment: Move the csrf token to under `<form method="post" action="">`

Comment: Check `formset.errors` in your view.

Comment: @Alasdair Thank you, I didn't realise you could do that and it helped me solve the problem. There was a model field that I had forgotten to exclude.

Answer (score 0):

When the formset is invalid, you typically don't redirect. That allows you to re-display the formset along with errors.

In your case, you are rendering the formset manually, so you are not displaying any errors. You could start with the simplest possible template.

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <table>
        {{ formset }}
    </table>
</form>
```

Once you're happy the view works, you can customize the template more. See the docs on [using formsets in templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/#using-a-formset-in-views-and-templates) for more info.

If you really want to redirect when the formset is invalid, you can check check `formset.errors` in your view to debug the problem.